# copyfromrecordset returns blank column

Tags: excel, vba, sybase

I am creating an ADODB connection to a Sybase database, executing an SQL statement into a recordset, and then using the CopyFromRecordset method to paste the contents of the recordset to a range. This has been working fine but I recently moved PC's at work and now one of the columns is returning nothing.

When I run the same SQL in SQuirreL the column is not blank.

If I pause the VBA and try to look at one of the values in the column / field in question (ie ?rst.fields(1).value in the immediate Window) I get the following error message:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Unspecified error.

In the Squirrel results Metadata tab the column in question is described as:

```
ColumnIndex 2
 getColumnName CommentText
 getColumnTypeName text
 getPrecision 2147483647
 getScale 0
 isNullable 0
 getTableName xxxxxxx
 getSchemaName 
 getCatalogName 
 getColumnClassName java.sql.Clob
 getColumnDisplaySize 2147483647
 getColumnLabel CommentText
 getColumnType 2005
 isAutoIncrement FALSE
 isCaseSensitive FALSE
 isCurrency FALSE
 isDefinitelyWritable FALSE
 isReadOnly FALSE
 isSearchable FALSE
 isSigned FALSE
 isWritable TRUE
```

The code in question is below, but, as stated the code does not seem to be the problem as it has worked previously - any ideas?

```
Sub ImportComments()

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim x As Long
Dim rngSQL  As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim sSQL As String
Dim sProvider As String
Dim sDS As String
Dim sDataSource As String
Dim sUser As String
Dim sCatalog As String
Dim sPassword As String
Dim rngDS As Range
Dim rngThisDS As Range
Dim sConnect As String
Dim sInstance As String
Dim fSuccess As Boolean
Dim sError As String

On Error GoTo ProcExit

'delete previous comments if they exist
If SheetExists("Comments_Data_Import", ThisWorkbook) = True Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comments_Data_Import").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

'create comments sheet
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EWI_Data_Import"))
wsData.Name = "Comments_Data_Import"

'build sql string
Set rngSQL = Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SQL").Range("A2"), _
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SQL").Range("A2").End(xlDown))
For Each cell In rngSQL
    sSQL = sSQL & cell.Value & " "
Next cell

'define login components
Set rngDS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Login").Range("rngInstance").CurrentRegion
Set rngDS = rngDS.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngDS.Rows.Count - 1)
sProvider = "Provider=ASEOLEDB.1;"
sUser = "User ID=" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Login").Range("rngUsername").Value & ";"
sPassword = "Password=" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Login").Range("rngPassword").Value

'try to log in to each instance exiting when succesful
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.CommandTimeout = 600

'turn off error hadling to allow for connection errors    On Error Resume Next

For Each rngThisDS In rngDS.Rows

    'complete connect string
    Err = 0
    sInstance = rngThisDS.Cells(1, 1)
    sDS = "Data Source=" & rngThisDS.Cells(1, 2) & ";"
    sCatalog = "Initial Catalog=" & rngThisDS.Cells(1, 3) & ";"
    sConnect = sProvider & sDS & sUser & sCatalog & sPassword


    'attempt to open
    cn.Open sConnect

    'If successful Then
    If Err = 0 Then

        'flag success
        fSuccess = True

        'execute SQL
        On Error GoTo ProcError
        Set rst = cn.Execute(sSQL)

        'copy data into comments sheet
        wsData.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst


        'Put in the headers
        Set rng = wsData.Range("A1")
        For x = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
            rng.Offset(0, x - 1).Value = rst.Fields(x - 1).Name
        Next x
        FormatComments
        Exit For
    End If

Next rngThisDS

If fSuccess = False Then
    MsgBox ("Unable to connect to Insight")
Else
       MsgBox "Connected to and exported data from " & sInstance
End If

ProcExit:
Set wsData = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set rngSQL = Nothing
Set cell = Nothing
Set rngDS = Nothing
Set rngThisDS = Nothing

Exit Sub

ProcError:

    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [CopyFromRecordset() MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa165427%28v=office.10%29.aspx):

> When this method copies the recordset to the worksheet, the results
>   will be truncated if you do not specify a range that is large enough
>   to hold the contents of the recordset.

Consider specifying the range with `MoveFirst` command reset:

```
' Copy data into comments sheet
rst.MoveLast
rst.MoveFirst
wsData.Range("A2:Z500").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

Or entire worksheet (starting at A1, of course inserting row for column headers)

```
wsData.Cells.CopyFromRecordset rst
```

But even then, `CopyFromRecordset()` is sensitive to data and cursory types even memory (since you pull all data and dump at once), so consider altogether replacing the method and iterate through records for the rows. Even other languages (PHP, Python, Java, etc.) run queries this way, opening cursor and iterating through resultset.

```
' Put in the headers
Set rng = wsData.Range("A1")
For x = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
      rng.Offset(0, x - 1).Value = rst.Fields(x - 1).Name
Next x

' Put in rows
Dim col As Integer, row As Integer
rst.MoveLast
rst.MoveFirst

Set rng = wsData.Range("A2")
row = 0
Do While Not rst.EOF
    For col = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
            rng.Offset(row, col).Value = rst(col)
    Next col
    row = row + 1
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: That fixed the problem for me, many thanks for that!! It just seems that CopyFromRecordset() is bugged.

Comment: I keep finding that CopyFromRecordset is dramatically faster than itterating through. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: @OliverMorrison, generally loops are more processing than single function calls (where iteration is done much faster at lower level like C++/C).

Answer (score 0):

I tried both solutions from Parfait, the first one gave me an error on `rst.MoveLast` of:

> Run-time error '-2147217884 (80040e024)': Rowset does not support
> fetching backwards

The second solution (iterating through rows) does work, but it's painfully slow on the workbook in my case.

What worked was to change the SQL query for a long text string field to `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000),FieldName) as FieldName`.
Limit for NVARCHAR is 4000, and VARCHAR limit is 8000, you can set it lower.

The column in question is defined as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in the DB which may be issue.